# Convert This Code to Vb.net

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

i can't convert this codes to vb.net. please help me. thank you.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace RssReader.Common
{
/// <summary>
/// Provides a standard change-notification implementation.
/// </summary>
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

i cant convert this code's to vb.net. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Not having the context of what you need this class for (its only a snippet after all, I attempted to perform a compilable conversion for you.  What this means is that the compiler says the syntax is right.  Based on my extensive knowledge of VB.NET and my growing C# skills I think this is likely the solution you need.

The real issue that most code converters miss here is that when you specify a default value for a parameter in VB.NET, you MUST use the keyword "Optional" in front of it. To their detriment most converters will also put the Attribute definition before the word Byval and after the word Optional which is not correct.  To correctly make a variable optional, you must put that keyword directly before the Byval.  Thus the only place for the attribute definition to go is before the word Optional.

Caveat.
Now, the compiler likes what I wrote, but I have no idea if it will work in your context having no access to the wider codebase that your calling it from.

Hope this helps, Code is below.

```
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace RssReader.Common
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Provides a standard change-notification implementation.
    ''' </summary>
    Public MustInherit Class BindableBase
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
            PropertyChangedEvent?.Invoke(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End Sub

        Protected Function SetProperty(Of T)(ByRef storage As T, ByVal value As T, <CallerMemberName> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing) As Boolean
            If Object.Equals(storage, value) Then
                Return False
            End If
            storage = value
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName)
            Return True
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```